# Problems with Notation of push-forward

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

I have a problem understanding the following notations of a paper:

Let $i:\mathbb{C}^* \hookrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and $p:\mathbb{C} \twoheadrightarrow \mathbb{C}^*$ be the inclusion and the universal cover of $\mathbb{C}^*$, $p=z\circ p=e^{2\pi it}$ for coordinate functions $z$ and $t$. Now let $f \in \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}}(U)$, then I have a problem understanding what exactly

$$\tilde{f} \in i_*p_*\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}}(U)$$

is. The author nowhere exactly defined, what $p^*$ and $p_*$ are, so I assumed its the standart pullback/pushforward notation. But since $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}}=\Omega^0_{\mathbb{C}}$ I dont quite get, how one is supposed to consider the pushforward on $0$-forms. Thinking of it as abuse of notation, meaning $p_*$ is also the pullback, I would end up with a strange map
$$i^*p^*f = i^*(f \circ p) = (f \circ p \circ i): \mathbb{C}^* \hookrightarrow \mathbb{C} \twoheadrightarrow \mathbb{C} \overset{f\vert_U}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^*$$

Comment: you can always do this when you have a map $f:X\to X$: because of adjointness you always have a map $F\to f_* f^* F$ for every sheaf F, and in the special case $F=O_X$ you have $f^* O_X=O_X$ so you get a map $O_X\to f_*  O_X$

Comment: so in this case i consider $f = p \circ i: \mathbb{C}^* \to \mathbb{C}^*$ and get $O_X \to f_* O_X = i_* p_* O_X$.